# Print immutable linked list in reverse order in a machine with small memory

Tags: linked-list

Given an immutable linked list having node.val and node.next, print the values in linked list in reverse order. And the linked list is too large to fit in the ram of our machine. Disk space is not allowed to use.

Comment: What have you tried ? You are expected to show us the code you have written, or at least the ideas that you have, or the line in the documentation that you do not understand, etc... What language do you use ?

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Hi Gabriel, sorry for the confusion. It's an interview question I did not come up with a good answer. I posted the question here just for any ideas that could solve this question. I use python but language actually does not matter. I want to listen you people's ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Where are these nodes coming from ? Are they read from a file on disk ?